# Find Security Groups in a Specific OU

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to find what Security Groups a member belongs so in a specific OU. Assume a directory structure like the following:

- testdom.myworld.com (domain)

  - Users (OU)

    - Aeys (OU)

      - A1 (SG)
      - A2 (SG)
      - A3 (SG)
    - Bees (OU)

      - B1 (SG)
      - B2 (SG)
    - Caes (OU)

      - C1 (SG)
      - C2 (SG)

Here is what I have tried so far. We created a user called A12Tester that belongs to the A1 and A2 security groups. I tried to get grab two groups by doing the following:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
    "testdom.myworld.com",
    "OU=Aeys, OU=Users, DC=testdom, DC=myworld, DC=com");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, name);
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

When I debug this, `results` ends up with security groups like `"Everyone"`, `"Authenticated Users"`, `"Users"`, and finally the ones I was looking for, `"A1"` and `"A2"`. The directory I am querying is dynamic, so I might not always be able to simply parse the results for the ones I want.

How can I narrow down my search to only return groups that are in the OU that I specify?

Comment: Two questions...

1) What do you mean by the directory is dynamic? Do you mean the path for the OU you're querying in?

2) Will the groups you're looking for be in the OU you specify or possibly be outside of it?

Comment: @codingChris 1) By dynamic, I mean that I can't hard code the names of the OUs because they may change. I only know the name of the OU that I am using to query. 2) The user could belong to groups outside of the OU I specify. I don't want those results. I only want to know about the user's security groups that are inside the OU I specify.